# Convergence between $\sum |a_n|$ and $\sum a_n z^n$ for all $z\in\mathbb{T}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Let $\{a_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of complex numbers. $\mathbb{T}$ is the unit circle over complex plane. It is obvious that if $\sum |a_n|$ converges, then $\sum a_n z^n$ converges for each $z\in \mathbb{T}$ fixed. **Is the converse also true?**
If the answer is “no”, what will happen if we strength the condition by assuming $\sum a_n z^n$ converges pointwise **and defined a continuous function on $\mathbb{T}$**?

---

Here are some observations.

1.Suppose $\sum a_n z^n$ converges pointwise on $\mathbb{T}$. Denote the limit function by $f$, then by Baire category theorem, $f$ is continuous except a set of first category.

2.I think this question may have some relations with the following question: find a function in disc algebra $A(\mathbb{D})$, and there is no analytic continuation of $f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See also this posting in MO by me: [Ordinary generating function for Mobius](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/126442/ordinary-generating-function-for-mobius).

The answer to your question is  **no**  even in the case of pointwise convergence and continuous on $\mathbb{T}$.

We modify the ordinary generating function for Mobius function slightly. Let $$
f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)}n z^n.
$$
The radius of convergence of the series is $1$, also the following argument shows the convergence on $\mathbb{T}$. Let $A_{\theta}(t)=\sum_{n\leq t} \mu(n)e^{2\pi i n \theta}$. By partial summation,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n\leq x} \frac{\mu(n)}n e^{2\pi i n \theta} &=\int_{1-}^x \frac1t dA_{\theta}(t)=\frac{A_{\theta}(t)}t \Bigg\vert_{1-}^x +\int_1^x \frac{A_{\theta}(t)}{t^2}dt
\end{align}
$$

By [Davenport's theorem](https://academic.oup.com/qjmath/article-abstract/os-8/1/313/1564796?redirectedFrom=PDF), for any fixed $h>10$ and uniformly for $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$
A_{\theta}(t) = O\left( \frac t{\log^h t}\right).
$$
The implied constant in the big-oh is absolute. Taking $x\rightarrow\infty$,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}n e^{2\pi i n \theta} = \int_1^{\infty} \frac{A_{\theta}(t)}{t^2}dt,
$$
the integral converges absolutely.

Fix $\theta_0\in\mathbb{R}$. By the uniformity in Davenport's theorem and the Dominated Convergence Theorem, we have
$$
\lim_{\theta\rightarrow\theta_0} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)}n e^{2\pi i n \theta}=\lim_{\theta\rightarrow\theta_0}\int_1^{\infty} \frac{A_{\theta}(t)}{t^2}dt=\int_1^{\infty} \frac{A_{\theta_0}(t)}{t^2}dt = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)}n e^{2\pi i n \theta_0}.
$$
Hence, we have the convergence of $f(z)$ for any $z\in \mathbb{T}$ and the pointwise limit is continuous on $\mathbb{T}$.

However, this series is not absolutely convergent. To see this, consider
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{|\mu(n)|}n = \infty. 
$$

Comment: Wow. This is really cool. I was really not expecting the Mobius function to crop up here. +1 from me

Comment: Agree with K.defaoite, this is really cool. Is this $f$ in disc algebra? From my observation, $\sum 1/n^2$ converges, so by Fatou theorem for Hardy space, the radius limit of the unit open disc is equal to $f$ almost every where.

Comment: Oh, I see, the fact that $f$ lies in the disc algebra is a direct corollary of solving continuous boundary Dirichlet-Laplace. Thank you, Kim.